# How do I make title of cell left aligned but center the rest of content?

Tags: html, css

I have two side by side table cells which stack when triggered by a media query for a HTML newsletter. I want the headlines "Be Ready" and "Stay Organized" to left align when the responsive code fires but the "margin: 0px auto" causes all of the content to center. Is there a way to get these to stay left aligned? If I move them out of the table data cell from the rest of the content, everything messes up.

The "Stay Organized" and "Be Ready" headlines are centered when the code is responsive. I need them left aligned instead.

This is what it's supposed to look like on mobile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEyPN.jpg

Any help is appreciated.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <!--

            -->
            <html lang="en">
            <head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <style type="text/css">
                table td {border-collapse:collapse;}   

                table[class=tblPreHeaderLinks] {
                    width: 100% !important;
                    height: 25px !important;
                    clear: both !important;
                    float: none !important;
                }

                .appleLinks2 a {
                    color:#333333 !important;
                    text-decoration: none !important;
                    }

                /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
                #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
                .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
                .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
                body, table, td, a{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
                table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
                img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;} /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */

                /* RESET STYLES */
                body{margin:0; padding:0;}
                img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
                table{border-collapse:collapse !important;}
                body{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}

                /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
                .appleBody a {color:#68440a; text-decoration: none;} 
                .appleFooter a {color:#999999; text-decoration: none;} 

                /* MOBILE STYLES */

                @media screen and (max-width: 525px) {

                    body[yahoo] .block_td {display: block;}
                    .appleLinks2 a {
                    color:#545861 !important;
                    text-decoration: none !important;
                    }




                    body {
                            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
                            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
                        }

                    div[class="mobilecontent"]{
                    display: block !important;
                    max-height: none !important;
                    }

                    /* ALLOWS FOR FLUID TABLES */
                    table[class="wrapper"]{
                      width:100% !important;
                    }

                    /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
                    td[class="mobile-hide"]{
                      display:none;}

                    img[class="mobile-hide"]{
                      display: none !important;
                    }

                    img[class="img-max"]{
                      max-width: 100% !important;
                      width: 100% !important;
                      height:auto !important;
                    }

                    a.learnMore {
                        display: block;
                        text-align: center;
                    }

                    /* UTILITY CLASSES FOR ADJUSTING PADDING ON MOBILE */

                    td[class="section-padding"]{
                      padding: 10px 15px 5px 15px !important;
                    }

                     /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
                    table[class="responsive-table"]{
                      width:100%!important;
                    }

                    td[class="weatherTEXT"]{
                      font-size: 23px !important;
                      line-height: 27px !important;
                    }

                    td[class="weatherTEXT2"]{
                      font-size: 17px !important;
                      line-height: 21px !important;
                    }

                }


            </style>
            </head>
            <body yahoo="fix" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
            <style type="text/css">
            body { width: 100% !important; }
            </style>

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="wrapper" style="border:1px solid #e2e0e0;">
            <tr>
            <td align="center">




            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
                <tr>
                <td align="center">



                    <!--BODY-->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#f6f4f5" align="center">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td width="640" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="section-padding" >

                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;" class="section-padding">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" class="responsive-table" align="center">
                                    <tbody>


                                    <tr><!--MOVABLE INK-->
                                    <td>
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td style="padding: 15px 15px 5px 15px;">
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr>


                                                    <td valign="top" width="290" class="block_td" style="margin:0px auto;">

                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
                                                             <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" style="font-family: Ariel, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 22px; line-height: 26px; color:#002663;padding:0px 0px 25px 0px;" colspan="2">
                                                                    <b>Be Ready.</b>
                                                                </td>

                                                            </tr>
                                                                <td rowspan="3" valign="top" width="57" style="padding-right:10px;;">
                                                                    <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Phone-35x73.jpg" width="35" height="73" alt="House getting hit by a fallen tree" border="0">
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td valign="top" align="left">
                                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding: -5px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; line-height:17px; padding-left:0px;">
                                                                            <b>Download our app:</b>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;">
                                                                                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0"> 
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td style="valign="top">&bull;</td>
                                                                                        <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;">Take pictures of damage</td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td valign="top">&bull;</td>
                                                                                        <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;">Submit your claim</td>
                                                                                    </tr>

                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style=" padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:35px;">
                                                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                                    <tbody><tr> 
                                                                                        <td class="mobile-hide">
                                                                                            <a href="http://www.movable-ink-7850.com/p/rp/aa8600496aa4ae32/url?MM_webID=%%WebID%%"><img src="http://www.movable-ink-7850.com/p/rp/aa8600496aa4ae32.png?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" alt="House getting hit by a fallen tree"></a>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>

                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </tbody></table>


                                                                            </td>                                      
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>                                                            
                                                                            <td style="padding-right:35px;">
                                                                                <!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
                                                                                <div class="mobilecontent" style="mso-hide:all;display:none;max-height:0px;overflow:hidden;" align="center">
                                                                                    <a href="http://www.movable-ink-7850.com/p/rp/aa8600496aa4ae32/url?MM_webID=%%WebID%%"><img src="http://www.movable-ink-7850.com/p/rp/aa8600496aa4ae32.png?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" border="0" alt="House getting hit by a fallen tree"></a>                                                 
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <!--<![endif]-->
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>

                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td valign="top" width="290" class="block_td" style="margin:auto;">
                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Ariel, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 22px; line-height: 26px; color:#002663;padding:0px 0px 25px 0px;" colspan="2">
                                                                    <b>Stay Organized.</b>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td rowspan="3" valign="top" width="60" style="padding-right:10px;">
                                                                    <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Icon-Devices-50x50.jpg" alt="" border="0">
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td valign="top" align="left">
                                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding: -5px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; line-height:17px; padding-left:0px;">
                                                                            <b>Visit eService today:</b>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;">
                                                                                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0"> 
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td valign="top">&bull;</td>
                                                                                        <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;"><span class="appleLinks2">24&#47;7 access</span></td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td valign="top">&bull;</td>
                                                                                        <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:17px;">Manage your policy online</td>
                                                                                    </tr>

                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td style="padding-top:2px;">
                                                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                                    <tbody><tr> 
                                                                                        <td class="mobile-hide">
                                                                                            <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/home-insurance/home-coverages-and-benefits/home-insurance-benefits/property-replacement-service?MM_webID=%%WebID%%"><img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Button-Sign-In-70x19.jpg"></a>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>

                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </tbody></table>



                                                                            </td>                                      
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>                                                            
                                                                            <td style="padding-top: 30px; padding-right:40px;">
                                                                                <!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
                                                                                <div class="mobilecontent" style="mso-hide:all;display:none;max-height:0px;overflow:hidden;" align="center">
                                                                                    <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/home-insurance/home-coverages-and-benefits/home-insurance-benefits/property-replacement-service?MM_webID=%%WebID%%"><img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Button-Sign-In-139x38.jpg" width="139" height="38" border="0" alt="House getting hit by a fallen tree">                                                      
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <!--<![endif]-->
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </table>

                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;" class="tdLine">
                                                    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tblLine">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; background-color:#f6f4f5" class="tdLineActual">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>                       
                                                    </table> <!-- tblLine -->
                                                </td> <!-- tdLine -->
                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody></table>


                                    </td>
                                    </tr><!--END OF MOVABLE INK-->





                                    </tbody></table>
                                </td>       
                            </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody></table><!--END OF BODY-->





                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table><!--END OF CONTAINER-->

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: you should really summarize your key problem. We can't spend a lot of time seeing whole of your code.

Comment: The "Stay Organized" and "Be Ready" headlines are centered when the code is responsive. I need them left aligned instead.

Comment: @user1011861 I think "Stay Organized" and "Be Ready" are left align already. I am using Mozilla Firefox and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

However i dont recommend to use nested tables but for your structure added one more table for desired results: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m6dkk7q6/)**

```
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```